# How to import android native apps in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to import a native app, such as dialer or mms.

but always failed to build. some resource like color etc. not found
and some class , such as NoNullCursorAsyncQueryHandler, also not resolved.

my step is :
1. start Android studio 
2. File->import project
3. select the source folder
4. clean & build.

the correct steps ?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean, `File -> import sample` on android studio? those sample projects from google?

Comment: no, File->Import project ,  then select the aosp app (download from android.developers.com).

Comment: It could be better to add a screenshot or even if there is an error then putting  it here.